# string typeError: variable is undefined

Tags: javascript

I am writing a little program with javascript and html canvas. It is my first javascript program. It will make the dragonCurve thing. But I am getting this error:`TypeError: old is undefined`. I am not the first one with this question but after reading the other questions I still couldn't find a solution.

The following code is part of the program where it raises an error.
So why does it give an error?

```
<script>
var r = 'r';
var l = 'l';

var old = r;
var newer = old;

var iteration = 10;
var cycle = 1;

while (cycle < iteration){
  newer = (old) + (r);
  old = old.reversed;

  var oldstring = old.split("");  <!-- here is the error -->

  cycle++;
}
</script>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce that error from the code you posted, but I do get one about iteration being undefined.

Comment: my bad there also needs to be `var iteration = 20;` at the top of the code

Comment: what is old.reversed supposed to do?

Comment: @BarryDoyle I changed my post. And yea there is cycle++ at the end (and inside) of the while loop.

Comment: @BarryDoyle old.reverse should  reverse the old string. So the first letter of old will be the last etc.

Comment: I'm not sure if reversed is a JS function, I think you need to define a reverse function so that old doesn't become undefined upon calling  old = old.reversed.  I've added an answer that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"reversed" isn't a default function in JavaScript.

You'll need to create and add a function like this one:

```
function reverse(s){
  return s.split("").reverse().join("");
}
```

Then replace `old = old.reversed;` with `old = reverse(old);`

This should solve the problem.

Comment: he's not even calling `reverse` as a function, he's using it as a property.

Comment: Final thing: you may want to clarify what you mean by "default function"

Answer (score 0):

Yeah so if he really wanted to he could also just say old.reversed ();

Comment: `reverse()` not `reversed()`, and you really should edit your already accepted answer instead of writing another - especially in this case because this is a better answer (provided you fix the function name)

Comment: It happens.  Mobile is really bad for SO, it doesn't get the context at all.